# What's the relationship between str and bytes in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

Consider the following typescript:

```
>>> s = 'a'
>>> isinstance(s, bytes)
True
>>> isinstance(s, str)
True
>>> isinstance(s, unicode)
False
>>> isinstance(s.decode('utf-8'), unicode)
True
```

How come `s` is both a `str` and a `bytes`? Is one of those a descendant of the other one?

How did I run into it? I was trying to find description of `decode` method in the docs. I couldn't find it for `str`, but was able for [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode).

Comment: `>>> isinstance(s, bytes) False` python 3

Comment: Added the Python 2.x tag, as this seems only to be the case in Python 2. Also, `bytes == str` yields `True` in Python 2.7

Comment: Indeed. I mainly deal with Python 3, so I instinctively looked in that part of the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong documentation.

This equivalence is only true in Python 2.7. There, `bytes` was introduced as an alias to `str` in order to ease migration to Python 3.

In Python 3, `str` is what was previously called `unicode`, `bytes` is the type that was previously called `str`.

The documentation for `str.decode` for Python 2 is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode).